# EntryAssembly for MAF AddIn

Tags: c#, appdomain, strongname, maf

Is there a way to setup MAF addins so that [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx) returns a reference to the addin's main assembly when called from inside the addin's AppDomain?

Background: to meet certain security requirements for my project, I must load addins in a separate AppDomain, and the result of GetEntryAssembly() must be set to the addin's (strongly named) main assembly when called from inside the addin's AppDomain. I've developed a test case following the pattern laid out in the [MSDN MAF walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788290.aspx). In my test case, GetEntryAssembly() always returns null if the assembly is loaded in a separate AppDomain (or process).

I notice the GetEntryAssembly documentation says "The GetEntryAssembly method can return Nothing when a managed assembly has been loaded from an unmanaged application"--does this apply to MAF's proxying across AppDomain boundaries?

The assemblies and executables in question all have strong names.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about this. It does return Nothing (null).

But note that in the [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx), the "Return Value" is described as:

> The assembly that is the process executable in the default application
>   domain, or the first executable that was executed by
>   AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly

[AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxx9f4c2.aspx) is used to execute the main method of a .NET application. In your case no application is executed. What is being done, is explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2007/06/28/behind-the-scenes-activation-pete-sheill.aspx).

It makes sense to return Nothing (null) because there was no call to ExecuteAssembly.

Why don't you use [GetExecutingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) instead?